# IE 11 returning negative year when creating new Date using MMM/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

When I try to use `new Date("Dec/30/2016")` it returns `Fri Dec 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (PHT)` but when I do this on IE11, it instead returns `Fri Dec 30 -2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (PHT)`

Is there a way to patch this up like a polyfill/shiv to make it work as expected?

https://jsfiddle.net/hx038a03/5/
[image]

Comment: momentjs is probably your best bet.

Comment: As you can see, the problem is on the Date object, even native javascript would fail on this scenario unless I can find a way to patch things up.

Comment: Don't parse date strings with the built-in parser, always use a bespoke function or library with a **decent** parser.

Comment: But even using momentjs returns the wrong answer.. why was this a duplicate? What I was looking for was a shiv..

Comment: hrmmm... @RobG I have to object to the duplicate. In this case, the input *stays the same* whereas the duplicate target is clearly about *different inputs representing the same date*. Also please read the above comment by reikyoushin.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier—I disagree. It's all about the OP depending on the built-in parser when that is a very bad idea. The [*duplicate I marked*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) explains why it's a bad idea, why different browsers may return different results (which is exactly the OP's problem) and how to address it. The bottom line is the OP should not use the built-in parser for this.

Comment: @reikyoushin—moment.js will correctly parse that format **if** you tell the parser the format to parse: `moment('Dec/30/2016','MMM/DD/YYYY')`. Perhaps you had the [*parse tokens*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) wrong (moment uses all upper case for the date parts and lower for time, except for 24hr which is HH). If that's your solution, include a moment.js tag, then post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @RobG You can see here https://jsfiddle.net/hx038a03/5/ that it does not return the expected Date when passing the format.. Try opening that one up in IE11

Comment: @reikyoushin—I tried it in IE 11 with moment.js and it worked fine, but I used the correct parse tokens. There are other parsers, try [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha).

Comment: @RobG hmm. yeah, that makes sense. If this question stays without answer, your initial decision will indeed become very sensible. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @RobG When you said it worked fine, have you checked that one in IE11? Cause in mine it returns -2016

Comment: @r— "*I tried it in IE 11 with moment.js*" means I tried `moment('Dec/30/2016','MMM/DD/YYYY')` in IE 11. ;-)

Comment: @RobG but in mine it shows `Fri Dec 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)` See https://jsfiddle.net/hx038a03/5/

Comment: @reikyoushin— **you're still using the wrong [*parse tokens*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)**, use MM/DD/YYYY (note the upper case). If you do not supply the parse format, moment.js will first try ISO 8601, then RFC 2882, then fall back to just `new Date(string)` which is why you see the same result if you don't give it any parse format. [*Read the documentation*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/). If you give it erroneous parse tokens, it will give you erroneous results: GI/GO.

Comment: @RobG But my string has "Dec" and not "12" thus the "MMM" and not the "MM"

Comment: But you're using "dd/yyyy" instead of "DD/YYYY".

Comment: Ahh yes, its the case of the letters that im missing. Thanks!